# Drag and drop fires only once in Telerik DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, telerik-grid

I'm trying implement drag and drop functionality in my user control which is actually one of my custom wizard steps.
I've implement all most all parts of code in the online demo http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx and faced with next situation : drag and drop fires only once. After this it doesn't work anymore unless I refresh page. There is no javascript errors, warnings or log messages in console. Behavior is the same in the different browsers. Does anybody familiar with this kind of issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Issue was in included RadAjaxPanel.
So it was like this RadAjaxPanel -> RadAjaxPanel -> DataGrid